# loop through 2D arrays and count the results for each row separately (Java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a 2D array that stores the answer yes/no when the user votes, so for my case row 1 is question 1, then when a question adds to the system it goes to row 2 etc. And the voter ID is the column, what I need is to count the number of yes/no answers to get the number of votes for each question.

I have managed to loop through the entire array and count the yes/no answers (which would work if i only wanted one question), however I can't seem to get my system to print the results for each row(question) in a loop.

**Here are my arrays that store the answers**

```
public static List<String[][]> voteList = new ArrayList<String[][]>();
public static String[][] arrayOfAnswers = new String[100][100];
public static List<Referendum> referendumList= new ArrayList<Referendum>();
```

**This is how I am storing the answers**

```
System.out.println("Enter your first name here: ");
    String first = Scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your surname here: ");
    String surname = Scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your city here: ");
    String city = Scanner.nextLine();

    User user1=new User();


    int vid=user1.getTheIndex(first, surname, city);
    System.out.println("Enter your answer for the question: ");
    String theanswer = Scanner.nextLine();



    if(theanswer.toUpperCase().equals("YES"))
    {
        arrayOfAnswers[qid][vid]=theanswer;
        voteList.add(arrayOfAnswers);
        System.out.println("Thanks for voting. \n");
    }

    else if(theanswer.toUpperCase().equals("NO"))
    {
        arrayOfAnswers[qid][vid]=theanswer;
        voteList.add(arrayOfAnswers);
        System.out.println("Thanks for voting. \n");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("You must enter a yes and no answer, please try again.");

    }
```

**And this is the loop where I am trying to count the yes/no answers for each row (question)**

```
for (Referendum q: Menu.referendumList)
    {   
        int i=0;
        int yesCount = 0;
        int noCount = 0;    


        for(int j=0; j<Menu.arrayOfAnswers[i].length; j++)
        {

            if(Menu.arrayOfAnswers[i][j] != null)
                {
                    if(Menu.arrayOfAnswers[i][j].equals("yes"))
                        {
                            yesCount++;
                        }
                    else if(Menu.arrayOfAnswers[i][j].equals("no"))
                        {
                            noCount++;
                        } 
                }
        }
        System.out.print("Referendum : " + q.question + " \n");
        System.out.println("Votes yes: " + yesCount);   
        System.out.println("Votes no: " + noCount + "\n");  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you use incorrect data structures for the problem. If you want to count the yes and no answers from a  list of questions, then you could use a `Map` data structure where the key would be the question (simplest would be a String) and the value would be an array containing actually 2 `Integer`s. But this is non intuitive. A better approach would be to create some domain objects and operate with them.

```
class Question {
 private String content;
 private Integer yesCnt;
 private Integer noCnt;
 ...
 // Getters and setters
}
```

and then you would only have a `List<Question> questions` ... and:

```
for (Question q : questions) {
 if (userAnswer.equals("yes") {
  q.setYesCnt(q.getYesCnt++);
 } else {
  q.setNoCnt(q.getNoCnt++);
 }
}
```

but here it could be improved a bit so:

```
class Question {
private String content;
private Integer yesCnt;
private Integer noCnt;

public void vote(String answer) {
 if (answer.equals("yes") {
  yesCnt++;
 } else {
  noCnt++;
 }
}
}
```

and you would have something more natural like:

```
for (Question q : questions) {
 q.vote(userAnswer);
}
```

and later you could do:

```
for (Question q : questions) {
  System.out.println("Question: "+q.getContent()+" Yes: "+q.getYesCnt()+" No: " + q.getNoCnt());
 //Or just override toString of Question... and do:
 // System.out.println(q);
 }
```

Comment: Would I not need my 2D array with this method? it makes sense though, and seems like the more logical approach

Comment: No, you wouldn't need it. But again, it depends. My approach is more of a OOP style...

Answer (score 0):

Your local `i` variable inside the `for` loop is never incremented, you're only counting for the first row. Since `int i = 0`, your `if` statements will only test for `Menu.arrayOfAnswers[0][j]`. If you have 2 questions, you should increment `i` by one when you are done counting the first row.

Comment: if I  increment i++, then it will count the votes in the first and second row (question) giving the wrong total of yes and no votes. say this for instance..

question1- [yes][no][yes][yes]
question2 -[no][no][yes][no]

I need the total count of yes and nos for the first row, then the total count of the second row, and if I add another question etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a 2D array `array2D`, if you want to process each element you have to loop through the rows and inside a row you have to loop through the elements of that row:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array2D.lenght; ++i){     // loop for the rows
    for(int j = 0; j < array2D[i].length; ++j){ //loop for the elements in each row
        // Do something with element j from row i: array2D[i][j]
    }
}
```

In your case the array is `Menu.arrayOfAnswers`. As you want counters per row (question), initialize the counters inside the loop for the rows (questions), just before looping through the elements of each row (question)

```
int yesCount;
int noCount;
for(int i = 0; i < Menu.arrayOfAnswers.lenght; ++i){     // loop for the questions
    yesCount = 0;
    noCount = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < Menu.arrayOfAnswers[i].length; ++j){ //loop for the answers in each question
        if(Menu.arrayOfAnswers[i][j] != null) {
            if(Menu.arrayOfAnswers[i][j].equals("yes")){
                yesCount++;
            }
            else if(Menu.arrayOfAnswers[i][j].equals("no")){
                noCount++;
            } 
         }
    }
}
```